# jQuery this() for textarea?

Tags: jquery, text, textarea

Hey! Another small problem (isn't it a bug in jQuery?).

I've got a textarea like this:

```
<textarea>Something</textarea>
```

I want to erase "Something" after clicking, so:

```
$("textarea").click(function() {
     $(this).text("");
});
```

Ok so far. There are problems when I want to change the "Something" text ONLY when there's "Something" in my textarea:

```
$("textarea").click(
function() {
    if ($(this).text() === "Something") {
        $(this).text("");
        }
});
```

It works amazing for all different inputs, but not for textarea. And it works excellent without "if" loop, so what's going on here? :)

Thanks a lot!

EDIT

Ok, so here's my "real code":

```
$(".inp").click(
function(){
    if($(this).val() === "Text" || $(this).val() === "Name" || $(this).val() === "Mail" || $(this).val() === "Site" ) {
        $(this).val(""); 
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<input type="text" name="name" class="inp" value="Name" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="email" class="inp" value="Mail" /> <br />                             <input type="text" name="site" class="inp" value="Site" />  
<textarea rows="12" name="text" class="inp">Text </textarea>
</div>
```

It works for all inputs, excepting textarea.

Comment: you have a space between `Text` and `<textarea>` that should be the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you sure there aren't any whitespaces (or newlines) within the textarea? something like this:

```
<textarea>
Something
</textarea>
```

If this is the case you could append `.trim()` to `$(this).text()` this will remove leading and trailing whitespaces.

I've created the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9ew32/) above and it works. Something else: I would suggest using `.focus()` instead of `.click`, so it still works if the user is using the keyboard for navigation. [Here is an example with `.focus()`](http://jsfiddle.net/9ew32/1/)

Comment: ZOMG, WHITE SPACES! I'm so lame. Sorry, sorry, sorry! :) You're a genius :)

Comment: sometimes you need another set of eyes to spot such errors. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 5):

Use `.val("")` instead of `.text("")`

If you're manipulating textareas content with JavaScript use the `value` attribute... the node contents are just for the HTML representation.

Comment: I've tried, vals work for other inputs but not for my textarea ;/

Answer (score 0):

There was whitespace after the "Text" and before the "".  `$(this).val() works on textareas, but the text in the textarea was "Text ", not "Text".

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/P2Mce/)